# gulp 4.0.0 is showing an error when i'm trying to run gulp on cmment line

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to making a new project,
I'm using here `gulpfile.ja` code

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile SASS
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Move JS Files to SRC
gulp.task('js', function(){
  return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Watch SASS & Serve
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function(){
  browserSync.init({
    server: "./src"
  });

  gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Move Font Awesome Fonts folder to src
gulp.task('fonts', function(){
  return gulp.src('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/fonts"));
});

// Move font awesome css file
gulp.task('fa', function(){
  return gulp.src('node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'serve', 'fa', 'fonts']);
```

but when I'm running `gulp` on my command line here showing an error like

```html
assert.js:60
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (D:\PracticeJob\bs4practice\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (D:\PracticeJob\bs4practice\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\PracticeJob\bs4practice\gulpfile.js:21:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Comment: [Related issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/undertaker/issues/54#issuecomment-314082908)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not allowed in gulp4:

```
gulp.task('default', ['js', 'serve', 'fa', 'fonts']);
```

Change to:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js', 'serve', 'fa', 'fonts');
```

Same with this:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function(){
```

Change to:

```
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', function(){
```

And change to:

```
  gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], 'sass');
```

You cannot just use gulp3 code in a gulp4 environment without making these changes.  The above are the mimimum changes you must make but there are many more you should make to fully utilize gulp4.  See, e.g., [gulp4 documentation: creating tasks](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks).

Comment: for gulp.watch in my case, I am able to run with this: (while upgrading from gulp 3 to gulp 4)

`gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss'], gulp.series('sass'));`